# Why does response.readEntity(Post.class) return null?

Tags: json, rest, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to get JSON data from REST resource and automatically convert it to Java Object with JSON-to-Java binding. I use Jersey framework 2.21 with jersey-media-moxy module as JSON provider in my client application .

I cannot figure it out why I get null instead of proper Post object when I do this:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://www.travelportland.com/wp-json");
Response response = webTarget.path("posts/9").request().get();
Post post = response.readEntity(Post.class);     // => null
```

The Post class implementation looks like this (at this point I only want to take 'title' field from JSON):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Post {
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

All works fine when I try to get String:

```
String postStr = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

or if I try to get some other resource:

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
Response response = webTarget.path("posts/9").request().get();
Post post = response.readEntity(Post.class);     // => com.example.Post@74e28667
```

It seems like this issue somehow related to structure or size of JSON data.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with MOXy. I am not sure what (maybe size, bad chars, I don't know). But I tested with Jackson, and it works fine. You might want to just make the switch Jackson if you can't figure it out with MOXy.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You will need to set the class annotation to ignore unknown properties if you are not model all the keys from the JSON

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Post {
```

Jackson will also recognize most JAXB annotations if you already using a bunch of them.

Also make sure you get rid of the the MOXy dependency of you will have to explicitly register `JacksonFeature.class` with the `Client`, to disable the MOXy provider.